AEC Data Model - Fetch Type Information for Elements Instance
I have issue with using AEC Data Model API is can't fetch which Type of Element belong to which element.
url = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/aec/graphql'
import requests
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token.access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Region': 'US'  # Optional, depending on your API setup
}
# Define the GraphQL query and variables
query = """
    query GetElementsFromCategory($elementGroupId: ID!, $propertyFilter: String!) {
        elementsByElementGroup(elementGroupId: $elementGroupId, filter: {query:$propertyFilter}) {
            pagination {
                cursor
            }
            results {
                id
                name
                properties {
                    results {
                        name
                        value
                        definition {
                            name
                            units {
                                id
                                name
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
"""

# Set the variables (you need to provide the actual elementGroupId and propertyFilter)
variables = {
    "elementGroupId": f"{element_group_id}",  # Replace with your actual element group ID
    "propertyFilter": "property.name.category==Furniture"  # Replace with your property filter property.name.category==Walls
}

# Send the POST request with the query and variables
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={'query': query, 'variables': variables})

How can we albe to get that ? Example we have a Wall elementid is 3232323 and I want get which type and information parameters properties belong to element id 3232323.
Any help is appreciated !
